# What is the difference between a simple polyhedron and a triangulated graph?

Tags: polyhedra, triangulations

On a famous website I've seen the following:
*The skeletons of the simple polyhedra correspond to the triangulated graphs, the smallest of which are illustrated above.* That "illustration above" shows only triangulated planar graphs.

- Does it mean that the skeleton of a square pyramide or a triangular prism is a also a triangulation?

or does "correspond" mean:

- a triangulated graph is the skeleton of a simple polyhedron?

or is it a wrong formulation?

@Manfred Weis: What confuses me is the last sentence on the **Simple polyhedron** page on Wolfram: *"The skeletons of the simple polyhedra correspond to the triangulated graphs,..."*
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimplePolyhedron.html

I understand the contrary: " triangulated graphs are the skeletons of simple polyhedra" but not the formulation above in Italics.

Comment: At least on [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangulatedGraph.html) the class of graphs that are defined to be triangulated are the planar graphs: "*A planar graph G is said to be triangulated (also called maximal planar) if the addition of any edge to G results in a nonplanar graph.
If the special cases of the triangle graph C_3 and tetrahedral graph K_4 (which are planar that already contain a maximal number of edges) are included, maximal planar graphs are the skeletons of simple polyhedra and are isomorphic to planar graphs with 3n-6 edges.*"

Comment: I think Wolfram is conflating simple polyhedra and simplicial polyhedra. A simplicial polyhedron has only triangular faces. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_polytope

Comment: Yes, Wolfram is wrong. The skeleton of a simple polyhedron is a 3-connected planar graph with all vertices of degree 3, whereas the skeleton of a simplicial polyhedron is a 3-connected planar graph with all faces of size 3. These are dual properties so the relation is close not not equality.